# How to draw LibGDX Sprite from Blank Constructor

Tags: java, android, constructor, sprite, libgdx

I'm trying to draw a `Sprite` in LibGDX. I can do it if I use a constructor that specifies a texture to use, such as

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("path")));
```

but if I instead use `Sprite();` and try to then use `setTexture` and/or `setRegion`, no picture is drawn. The API says that a "texture, texture region, bounds, and color" need to be set before anything can be drawn. I've made calls to `setTexture`, `setRegion`, and `setColor` although nothing is being drawn.

Main question: If I use the default `Sprite()` constructor, what do I have to do afterwards to make sure it draws to the screen (in a `SpriteBatch`)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume the code'll need to do the very same steps as the [Sprite(Texture) ctor does](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java):

```
public Sprite (Texture texture) {
    this(texture, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
}

public Sprite (Texture texture, int srcX, int srcY, int srcWidth, int srcHeight) {
    if (texture == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("texture cannot be null.");
    this.texture = texture;
    setRegion(srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight);
    setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    setSize(Math.abs(srcWidth), Math.abs(srcHeight));
    setOrigin(width / 2, height / 2);
}
```

These are all public methods.